# Javascript. Перестает работать скрипт после первой итерации. Консоль ошибок не выдает

Tags: javascript

Есть трехмерный массив в котором лежат картинки к вопросам, сами вопросы и варианты ответов на них. При первом нажатии скрипт отрабатывает, дальше перестает работать (консоль ошибок не выдает).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var Question = [ // Трехмерный массив с данными
           ["image1.jpg","Вопрос 1",["Да","Нет"]],
           ["image2.jpg","Вопрос 2",["Разрешено","Запрещено","Затрудняюсь ответить"]],
           ["image3.jpg","Вопрос 3",["Первый вариант","Второй вариант","Третий"]],
           ["image4.jpg","Вопрос 4",["Да","Нет"]]
      ];

  var image = document.getElementById("image"); // Получаем элемент img
  var question = document.getElementById("question"); // Получаем элемент div
  var variantAnswer = document.getElementById("variant"); // Получаем элемент ol
   
  var i = 0; // Счетчик 1
  var j = 0; // Счетчик 2

   image.src= Question[i][0];// Выводим первую картинку
   image.alt= Question[i][0];// Для наглядности чтобы не подгружать картинки
   question.innerHTML = Question[i][1];// Выводим 1 вопрос
   while(j<Question[i][2].length){// Выводим первые ответы
       variantAnswer.innerHTML += "<li>"+Question[i][2][j]+"</li>";
       j++;
   }

   $("#variant li").click(function(){// При нажатии на ответ
       i++;// Увеличиваем счетчик
       j = 0;// Обнуляем счетчик
       image.src= Question[i][0];// Меняем картинку
       image.alt= Question[i][0];// Для наглядности чтобы не подгружать картинки
       question.innerHTML = Question[i][1];// Меняем вопрос
       variantAnswer.innerHTML = "";// Очищаем поле с ответами
       while(j<Question[i][2].length){// Выводим новые ответы
           variantAnswer.innerHTML += "<li>"+Question[i][2][j]+"</li>";
           j++;
       }
   });
  });
```

```css
img, ol li {margin-bottom: 10px;}
ol li {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image" src="" alt="">
 <div id="question"></div>
 <ol id="variant"></ol>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы задаёте действие не созданным ещё элементам.
Слушайте всё DOM дерево:

Поменяйте:

```
$("#variant li").click(function(){// При нажатии на ответ
```

На

```
$(document).on("click", "#variant li", function(){// При нажатии на ответ
```

Comment: Вау!!! Спасибо))) Так долго не мог понять в чем дело. Помогло!